# django allauth and PKCE

Tags: django-rest-framework, openid, django-allauth, pkce

I have to get login credentials from a 3rd service which require a PKCE to authenticate.
I was thinking to use django-allauth to do it but I can't find a way to send the pkce in my request. There is nothing fancy in the way I'm doing it.

I generate a PKCE but where can I add it in the allauth request ?

The configuration is quite simple atm, I did a custom SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS in my settings.py. It contact the server but the PKCE ( code_challenge ) is missing.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "auth0": {
        "AUTH0_URL": provider,
        "APP": {
            "client_id": client_id,
            "secret": secret
            "key": "",
            "code_challenge": code_challenge
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `AUTH_PARAMS`

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "auth0": {
        "AUTH0_URL": provider,
        "APP": {
            "client_id": client_id,
            "secret": secret
            "key": "",
        },
       'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'code_challenge_method': 'S256',
            'code_challenge': '362t6atUC1Fz'
        }
    }
}
```